# Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly

Tags: python

I'm using Visual Studio Code (Version 1.16.1) with Python Extension (Don Jayamanne version 0.7.0).  As I finish debugging a script, I consistently get an error - "Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly".  This happens regardless of execution process (Integrated or External terminal/console).

I'm an instructor for a Python class and all of my students are having to clear this error every time they debug.  I and my students would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

in my case removing .vscode folder in my user folder and reinstalling debugger extension helped